# CLGeocoder doesn't return anything

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to determine the iPhone user's location using a CLLocationManager and CLGeocoder.

My CLLocationManager seems to work well, but unfortunately the CLGeocoder doesn't do what I would like it to do.

Some code excerpts:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"Location updated to: %@",newLocation);

    [self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Reverse geocoding finished");

        self.currentPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.currentPlacemark.locality);
        NSLog(@"%@",self.currentPlacemark.ISOcountryCode); 

    }];
}

- (void)getCurrentLocation {

    NSLog(@"Determining current location");

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getCurrentLocation];
}
```

*self.currentPlacemark* is a *CLPlacemark* object.

*self.geocoder* is a *CLGeocoder* object.

*self.locationManager* is a *CLLocationManager* object.

What am I missing? Why isn't this working? 
I honestly spent hours and I'm slowly starting to become desperate …

Comment: Can you be more specific with "doesn't do what I want it to do"?   In particular, what's it doing? or not doing?

Comment: Sure, sorry for not being clear in that point: The completionHandler block is never being entered (or in other words: I never see the logging statement "Reverse geocoding finished")

Comment: have you alloc and init your geocoder?

Comment: Uhm … now I'm in a  very precarious position: I really forgot to alloc and init the geocoder. Why is it always that basic stuff which slows me down? Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @Patrick you are welcome, and i post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should alloc and init your geocoder.

```
self.geocoder = [[[CLGeocoder alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Reverse geocoding finished");

    self.currentPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.currentPlacemark.locality);
    NSLog(@"%@",self.currentPlacemark.ISOcountryCode); 

}];
```